# How can I change the class attribute value of a dynamically-created image?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an empty body element.
On every click, a JS click handler appends an image to event.clientX and event.clientY.

This works,but now I want the created images to fade in nicely. I am not sure if I will need a setTimeout somewhere for this.

So I have just tried to add a class with a transition, the JS function looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
var currentImg; // this is for later
var ix = event.clientX;     // Get the coordinates
var iy = event.clientY; 
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", images[0]);
x.setAttribute("width", "304");
x.setAttribute("height", "228");
x.style.position="absolute";
x.style.top= iy + 'px';
x.style.left= ix + 'px';   // display image where the click event happened
x.style.opacity = 0.1;      // set opacity to 0.1
document.body.appendChild(x);
x.classList.add("fadeIn");      // add the fadeIn CSS class
var ix = null;                  // reset the position variables
var iy = "";
console.log(ix);

});
```

The CSS classes look like this, both do not work

```
.fadeIn{
opacity:1;

 }

 .img{
transition: all 1s;
 }
img:hover{
opacity:1;
}
```

The class is added via JS according to dev tools, but the opacity change does not happen. So I have tried to add the hover class, and that does not change the opacity either.

Why is the class added, but the opacity does not change, is this because it is a new element added to the DOM?
And how can I elegantly fade the images in on click? Please no jQuery, I can do this with jQuery.

Here is the codepen

https://codepen.io/damPop/pen/RqMxex

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use img (Element) instead of .img (class)

also

```
x.style.transition = 'all 1s';
```

or

```
x.classList.add('img');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for you. https://codepen.io/rikin/pen/mQGBgq

Your problem is 2 parts:

```
.img // class
```

And using inline styling specificity which overrides your class styling

Ideal solution will add a class name to added element using Javascript.